# sql slect подсчитать результатирующую выборку за определенный период

Tags: sql

подскажите пож-та как правильно можно подкорректировать уже выбранные данные в select выборки 
есть уже результатирующие данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

задача такая что мне нужно из результатирующей выборки на текущий день посчитать по формуле за общее к-во за предыдущие 3 дней

SUM(HighCount) - SUM(LowCount) / SUM(AllCount) -- только сумма за предыдущиме 3 дня

в результате я должен получить 
все даты и к ним расчет к примеру на

```
15.04 , (15+34+31) - (0+2+0) / (17+37+32) * 100 = 90.6 %
14,04 , (34+31+11) - (2+0+1) / (37+32+12) * 100 = 90.12 %
и т.д
```

буду очень признателен за помощь в данном расчете

mysql = 5.6

Comment: Самое простое - взять три копии таблицы да связать их по разности дат.

Comment: хотелось бы решение в селекте 
пробую решение с 
     SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2019-04-06' AND  '2019-04-15' THEN  `count` ELSE 0 END) AS 'count1',   но он не корректно работает

Comment: Если хочется использовать групповую SUM() - то потребуется две копии таблицы. Кстати, можно будет не ограничиваться 3 днями, задавая диапазон как параметр.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.data, 
100*( t1.HighCount+t2.HighCount+t3.HighCount
     -t1.LowCount -t2.LowCount -t3.LowCount)
   /(t1.AllCount  +t2.AllCount  +t3.AllCount) percent
FROM table t1, table t2, table t3
WHERE t1.data = t2.data + INTERVAL 1 day
  AND t1.data = t3.data + INTERVAL 2 day
```

Само собой первые две даты выпадут, ибо у них нет двух "ранних" соседей. Также будет дыра, если отсутствует какая-то промежуточная дата. Ну и как бы предполагается, что поле даты уникально.